# Working with NSUserdefault and arrays swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm making an quote app and it would be a nice functionality to be able to allow users to "favourite" quotes and be able to pass this data for display in another array, a previous possible solution to this question without NSUserdefaults would be something like

```
var favouriteQuotesArray: [String] = []

    func makeQuoteFavourite() {

        let currentQuote = dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]
        favouriteQuotesArray.append(currentQuote)
    }
```

but that didn't work out and wasted me quite a while. But you see **what I'm trying to achieve is to be able to take out some string located at some index in my array (in this case the dream array) and then append this to another global array for displaying in another viewController.** Now I'm thinking about NSUserdefaults and store this into an array when a button is clicked like:

```
@IBAction func favour() {

//some NSUserdefaults statement to save this to a global array which I would be able to call in a view controller. 
}
```

How would I do something like this? Is there any alternatives?
P.S. Last thing for my project please give any helpful and detailed advice you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

```
 var favouriteQuotesArray: [String]? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("thekey") as? [String] 

                    func makeQuoteFavourite() {
                        if favouriteQuotesArray == nil {
                        favouriteQuotesArray = []
}
                        let currentQuote = dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]
                        favouriteQuotesArray!.append(currentQuote) 
                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(favouriteQuotesArray!, forKey: "thekey")
                    }

            @IBAction func favour() {
                 makeQuoteFavourite()
            }
```

Then, you can access it anywhere like this.

`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("thekey")`

Comment: Alright man, my one hour is up all based on the legitimacy of you answer. Please ensure that this is correct.

Comment: I have many view controllers which all need the same functionality do i copy this across all?

Comment: You could just add more variables to the same `struct`

Comment: Seems to get error use of unresolved identifier on declaration.

Comment: Make sure the struct is outside of the class declaration

Comment: Would you like to move this to the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84815/discussion-between-epic-defeater-and-newbeginnings).

Comment: Works! But please elaborate on how to put in multiple view controllers.

Comment: Can we talk in the chat?

Comment: Need a way to remove a element from the array.

Comment: Hey, you can do that by, first, getting the user defaults by writing this `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("thekey") as! [String]` then you can edit it and, once you are done, you can write this code to save it `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(theEditedArrayOfStrings, forKey: "thekey")` and that will do it